# Python opexpyxl's column_dimensions.width actually changes dimension on print, why so?

Tags: python, openpyxl

this is a code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    book = load_workbook('test_units.xlsx')
    sheet = book.active
    print(sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width)
    print(sheet.row_dimensions[3].height)
    book.save('test_units1.xlsx')
```

and this is how orignial xlsx looks:
[original doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuQXY.png)

after saving sheet as new doc:
[doc copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16klE.png)

I expected this 2 xlsx to be the same after printing their dimensions, but they are not, copied file has wider columns than original one.
Am i missing something?

Python 3.11, windows 10, openpyxl 3.1.2

I tried to use older openpyxl (3.0.7) versions, but nothing changed.

Comment: Technically I believe the row and column dimensions are supposed to None until they are actually used to change the value. Printing the object creates the object and the column with is assigned the width `DEFAULT_COLUMN_WIDTH = BASE_COL_WIDTH + 5` (which now 8 + 5 =13 )so the column is being set to 13 units wide when the workbook is saved. What is it you are trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions are created on demand to avoid annoying KeyErrors, and the default width will be set to avoid Excel assuming `width=0` which it otherwise does. Best inspecting `column_dimensions` for membership (note columns) can be grouped.